# bootstrapValidator check input letters mix numbers

Tags: javascript, bootstrapvalidator

I have a form using bootstrap validator.

```
fields: {
            account: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 4,
                        max: 8,
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+$/,
                    }
                }
            },
```

1. I need to check if the account input contains at least 1 letter & 1 number
2. another input is required to check characters only in Chinese

Does anyone know how to set this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.bootstrapValidator.validators.account = {
        validate: function(validator, $field, options) {
            var value = $field.val();

            if( value.match(/\d+/g) && value.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g) ) {
                return {
                    valid: true,    // or false
                }
            }

            return {
                valid: false,
                message : 'must contain 1 english character & 1 number'
            }
        }
    };
}(window.jQuery));

account: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 4,
                        max: 8,
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+$/,
                    },
                    account:{}
                }
```

I have found solution, please above